# Determine the set of points that satisfy the condition $Im \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 }=0$ where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are fixed complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the set of points that satisfy the condition $Im \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 }=0$ where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are fixed complex number.

Since $Im\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 }=0$, then there is no imagining part in $\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 }$, thus there exist a real number $t$ such that

$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 }=t$

Let $z=x+iy , z_1=a+ib, z_2=c+id,$ where $x,y,a,b,c$,and $d$ are real number and $a,b,c,$and $d$ are fixed. Then we have

$$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 }=\frac{x+iy-a-ib}{x+iy-c-id}=t$$

$$x+iy-a-ib=t(x+iy-c-id)$$

$$x+iy-a-ib=tx+ity-tc-itd$$

$$x+iy-tx-ity=a+ib-tc-itd$$

$$x(1-t)-iy(1-t)=a+ib-tc-itd$$

$$x-iy=\frac{a+ib-tc-itd}{1-t}$$

From this point I think I can say $\overline z =\frac{a+ib-tc-itd}{1-t}$. However, how can I guarantee that $t \not =1$

I tried to break this in 2 cases. One case is $t=1$ and another is $t \not =1$.

Can I assume that $z_1 \not = z_2$ otherwise

$$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 }=1$$
and any point $z$ will work?

Comment: The second-last of the string of equations should have $x(1-t)+iy(1-t)$ on the left-hand side.  You get $z$ instead of $\overline{z}$ in the final equation.  Yes, break it into two cases, and your conclusion is correct.

Comment: Geometrically, if the ratio is real, then the complex numbers are either in the same direction, or $180^{\circ}$ apart.  The solution is the line joining $z_1$ and $z_2$.  That is why, if $z_1=z_2$, any $z$ will do - it is on the line joining $z_1$ and $z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach which will guide you to the solution: Try to write 
$$\frac{(x+yi)-(a+bi)}{(x+yi)-(c+di)}$$
as $r+si$ (where $r,s \in \mathbb{R}$). You may start with the following steps:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(x+yi)-(a+bi)}{(x+yi)-(c+di)}& =\frac{(x-a)+(y-b)i}{(x-c)+(y-d)i} \\
\\
& =\frac{((x-a)+(y-b)i)((x-c)-(y-d)i)}{(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2}\tag{$*$}
\end{align}$$
Note the application of the binomial theorem. Now, you have to apply some routine calculations in order to write the term ($*$) as $r+si$. Then, set $s=0$ and you will see how to choose $x$ and $y$.

Comment: this is the most painful way to solve a problem.

Comment: I think this is one standard approach for solving such a problem. Not really imaginative, but it will definitely work!

Answer (score 1):

Denote $A,\,B,\,M$ the points representing the numbers $z_1,\,z_2,\,z$ respectively. Then $(z-z_1)$ gives the vector $\vec{MA}$ and $(z-z_2)$ the vector $\vec{MB}.$

$Im \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 }=0$ says that the vectors $\vec{MA},\,\vec{MB}$ are collinear, but $M\neq B.$

**The set of points $M$ is the straight line $AB$ without the point $B.$**