# Geometric meaning of Im$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I want to consider the geometric meaning of Im$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}=0$ and Re$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}=0$.
I know that subtracting by $z_1$ will be some sort of vertical or horizontal shift.  Then, dividing by $z-z_2$ will result in a stretch or shirnk of $z-z_1$, as long as $z-z_2$ is real-valued, and if $z-z_2$ is complex-valued then we will also have a rotation of $z-z_1$.  So, if the imaginary part is equal to $0$, then we know that these transformations has transformed $z$ to the real axis, and if the real part is equal to $0$, then these transofrmations has transformed $z$ to the imaginary axis.

I am wondering if this is a good way of thinking about these things, if anyone has anything to add, or if my thought process is incorrect in some way.  Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1562323/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1127705/42969

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1502492/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1627133/42969.

Comment: Thank you, Martin.  I do appreciate it!